# Fibonacci numbers function in CLIPS

Tags: fibonacci, clips

I can't create function for finding fibonacci numbers in CLIPS
i tryed

```
(deffunction fibo (?a  )
( if (> ?a 0) then  (+ fibo(- ?a 1) fibo(- ?a 2)) else (0)))
```

but it's doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function of calculating Fibonacci numbers recursively in CLIPS:

```
(deffunction fibo (?a)
    (if (or (= ?a 0) (= ?a 1)) then
        ?a
    else 
        (+ (fibo(- ?a 1)) (fibo(- ?a 2)))))
```

I don't understand, what your code does but there is error in it (you've missed brackets):
(deffunction fibo (?a  )
( if (> ?a 0) then  (+ **(** fibo(- ?a 1) **) (** fibo(- ?a 2) **)**) else (0)))

Comment: thanks, i works with clips first time, so i made a lot of syntax mistakes,